About the extension $k(t)/k(t^p)$

We aim to prove that $k(t)/k(t^p)$ is not Galois. I think that it's trying to prove that $|\mathrm{Gal}(k(t)/k(t^p))|\neq[k(t):k(t^p)].$ Now, I try to prove that $x^p-t^p$ is irreducible in $k(t^p)[X]$, then we have $$[k(t):k(t^p)]=\deg(\min(k(t^p,t))=p\neq 1=|\mathrm{Gal}(k(t)/k(t^p))|,$$
then $k(t)/k(t^p)$ is not Galois.
Since $\mathrm{char}(k)=p$, so $x^p-t^p=(x-t)^p$ in $k(t^p)[X]$, It looks quite right that it's irreducible, but how can I prove it more precisely.

Characteristic $p\cdot0?$ what is going on in that image?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension

Oh, sorry! It's p>0.

Indeed, $x^p-t^p$ is irreducible, see the duplicate target. I do want to commend the Exercise. Simply because it suffices to show that $t\notin k(t^p)$ to use the argument. We have found a polynomial with its coefficients in the base field such that $t$ is its only zero. Hence that also applies to the minimal polynomial. As long as we know that the minimal polynomial is not linear, this means that we are done.
